# Proofreading my code with proper loop usage

Tags: c, loops

This program is running and functioning properly until the end. When asking user if they want to continue or not, it should print "You have chosen to quit" after the first iteration if they choose to quit. The problem is that when asking whether to continue or quit, if user chooses quit, it brings main instructions back.

disregard the continue function i commented out.

```
/*This program was created to
  generate user-entered number of sets 
  of 6 random, non-repeating numbers. 
  Bradley Ruiz
  N01441960
  COP2220
  Mr. Snedden
  Project 2
*/

#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define OFFSET 1 //Defined Constants indicating the beginning
#define RANGE 53//and ending of range of random numbers to choose from.

void Flush(void);

/*int ContinueFunc(void){
  int success = 0, numSets = 0;
  char c;

  printf("You have completed your random number generation.\n");
  printf("Would you like to continue with more sets or quit?\n");
  printf("Enter 'q' or 'Q' to quit or a new number of sets to generate.");
  success = scanf(" %d" , &numSets); //scans user input and assigns the value to success.

  if(success == 0){//checks if the value of numSets is the same as originally declared or if it has changed. 
  scanf(" %c", &c); //if it is still 0, then it scans for a character entry.

  if(tolower(c) == 'q')
  return -1; //exits the function
  }//end if

  else
  return numSets;//if previous if statements are not true, it returns the numSets value.

  }*/
int PrintRand(int COUNT) { //Declaring my PrintRand function taking in an integer variable named COUNT returning no value.
    uint64_t nums = 0; //declaring local variables. 64bit variable to store all random numbers generated.
    unsigned num = 0; //number that is always >= 0.
    int i, j, success = 0, numSets = 0;
    char c;
    int duplicate = 0; //variable to check for repeating numbers.

    if(COUNT > 0){
        printf("Your %2d set(s) of 6 random numbers is:\n" , COUNT);
    }//prints out the number of sets the user chose.

    for (int cnt = 0; cnt < COUNT; cnt++) { //outer loop to repeat for the number of user entered sets.
        for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {//inner loop to generate 6 random numbers.
            do {
                num = (rand() % RANGE) + OFFSET; //generate a random number does a modulus operation by the max value of range and adds offset to ensure number is between 1-53.

                for (duplicate = 0, j = 0; j < 6; j++)//for loop to check for duplicates.
                    // retrieving the nth number from nums
                    if (((nums >> (j * 8)) & 0xff) == num)
                        duplicate = 1;

                if (duplicate) // if there is a repeating number, it will restart.
                    continue;

                nums |= (uint64_t)(num << (i * 8));//if not it saves the value to nums. 

                break;//breaks out of the do while loop.
            } while (1);

            printf("%2d " , num);//prints the random number with a set width while the conditions are true.

        }//end inner loop
        printf("\n");
    }//end outer loop
    printf("\n");
    printf("You have completed your random number generation.\n");
    printf("Would you like to continue with more sets or quit?\n");
    printf("Enter 'q' or 'Q' to quit or a new number of sets to generate.\n");
    success = scanf(" %d" , &numSets); //scans user input and assigns the value to success.

    if(success == 0){//checks if the value of numSets is the same as originally declared or if it has changed. 
        scanf(" %c", &c); //if it is still 0, then it scans for a character entry.

        if(tolower(c) == 'q')
            return -1; //exits the function
        //end if
    }
    else
        PrintRand(numSets);//continuation loop that calls itself if a user chooses another number of sets to generate.      

}//end of PrintRand function.

int PrintInstructions(void){//Function to print instructions taking in no value and returning in an integer value of the user input.  

    int numSets = 0; //local variables for PrintInstructions function.

    int success = 0;

    char c;

    for(;;){
        printf("******************************************************************\n");
        printf("Enter the amount of sets of 6 random numbers you want to generate.\n");
        printf("Enter in 'q' or 'Q' to quit...\n");
        printf("******************************************************************\n");

        success = scanf(" %d" , &numSets); //scans user input and assigns the value to success.

        if(success == 0){//checks if the value of numSets is the same as originally declared or if it has changed. 
            scanf(" %c", &c); //if it is still 0, then it scans for a character entry.

            if(tolower(c) == 'q')
                return -1; //exits the function
        }//end if

        else
            return numSets;//if previous if statements are not true, it returns the numSets value.

    }//end for

} //end PrintInstructions function.


int main() {
    srand(time(NULL)); //seeds system time so that each set of random numbers is different.
    int numSets = -99;

    do{

        numSets = PrintInstructions(); //calls print instructions function and sets the return value = to numSets variable.

        if(numSets > 0){     
            PrintRand(numSets);
        }//end if - statement that calls the Print Rand function if the numSets variable is greater than 0.

    }//end do - Loop will run until user enters the quit value.

    while(numSets != -1);// end do-while loop - Loop will run until numSets = -1 which is the quit value.

    printf("You have chosen to quit");
    return 0;
}

void Flush(){

    char c;

    while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);

    return;
}
```

Comment: Run your program in a debugger or use basic debug print statements. At a minimum you should be able to work out whether `PrintInstructions` returns `-1` and if not why not. [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: You're asking the question in two places: `PrintInstructions()` and `PrintRand()`. But you only break out of the loop when you get `-1` from `PrintInstructions()`.

Comment: To start, the posted code does not cleanly compile.  When compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  Note: other compilers use different options to produce the same information.

Comment: regarding: `printf("You have chosen to quit");`   TO have the text immediately displayed on the terminal, end the text with `\n'  or better use: `puts( "You have chosen to quit" );` which will automatically pass a '\n' to the `stdout` stream, thereby forcing a flush of the output buffer to the terminal.

Comment: regarding: `char c;

    while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);`   The function: `getchar()` returns an `int`, not a `char` AND depending on if `char` is `signed` or `unsigned`, it may not be able to recognize EOF`

Comment: regarding: `printf("Enter 'q' or 'Q' to quit or a new number of sets to generate.\n");
    success = scanf(" %d" , &numSets);`  a ascii char is read with a `%c`.   The input format conversion specifier: `%d` will only input digits and a leading '-' or '+' sign.  Suggest changing the test to `0` rather than a `char`

Comment: if scanf doesnt read a integer it is still 0 and that is what success is initially initialized at. that is what the if statement is for.